# using mysqldump to restore database to mysql located on another computer

Tags: mysql

Any idea how to do this restore ?
I looked into help of mysqldump but couldn't see it there .
If so can you give me some example.

Comment: another computer means another server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `mysqldump` you will generate a script you can use for restore on a different computer like this:

```
$ mysql -U user_name < your_backup.sql
```

Run on your favorite shell (windows command prompt, bash, csh...).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use CMD to navigate to the mysqldump location, then type this command,

`mysqldump database_name -u username >location\to\save\dump.sql`

change `database_name` to the `database you want to backup`, `username` to the `username associated with the database`, and `location\to\save\dump.sql` to the location where you want to save the output sql file, for me I wrote it D:\dump.sql

Then on the other machine you can import the SQL file using the PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: nice! didn't know about the PHPMyAdmin option.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute the SQL using the `mysql` command-line command. There is a switch to specify which file to import, I think it is `-I` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's just plain SQL. Pass the file to mysql (the mysql command line tool) and it will execute it:

```
mysql < backup.sql
```

Comment: but how i tell it to what database i want it to be restored ?

Comment: that's in the backup.sql file you get out of mysqldump. By default, the database will have the same name. But you can change it of course. Look for a line similar to: use dbname

Answer (score 0):

1. From the shell prompt, using
   parameters form the mysqldump
   [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html),  mysqldump the database using a `>` redirect to a
   human readable .sql file. E.g.

   `$ mysqldump --databases src_db > src_db.sql`
2. Transfer the human readable file to
   another machine.
3. After making sure the destination database exists has been created, redirect `<` the .sql file into the destination database.

   `$ mysql dest_db < src_db.sql`